# Android Framelayout with two custom views

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-framelayout

So I am currently using a framelayout to hold two custom views and a scrolling text view so that they are all stacked on each other.

Here is my XML file for the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".canvas.CanvasActivity"
>


<com.alastech.andyluo.crowdshout_androidapp.canvas.ShoutCanvasView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/shout_canvas"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<com.alastech.andyluo.crowdshout_androidapp.canvas.FeatureShoutView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/feature_shout"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="232dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/messageScrollView"
    android:layout_marginTop="167dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/messageTextView" />
</ScrollView>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/canvas_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

This should be putting a text view on top of a featureShoutView on top of a shoutCanvasView.

Instead it is sandwiching the text view in between my two custom views. Both featureShoutView and shoutCanvasView are drawing onto canvases. Any idea what may be causing this issue? Is it possible that two canvases don't play nice in a single layout? Any help is appreciated and I can provide more details as needed.

Comment: Hi @user5891328 can you explain more clearly what you need? As far as I understood, you want it this way 1) Toolbar 2) Textview below toolbar 3) featureShoutView below textview 4) shoutCanvasView below featureShoutView.. Did I get you correct?

Comment: @RaviSravanKumar This is exactly what I need except the order it's drawing in now is 1) Toolbar 2) featureShoutView 3) textview 4)shoutCanvasView

Comment: I think you can can use Linear Layout for this one with horizontal orientation.